# Chrome Extension User Upload Image

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering if it's possible to allow the user to upload an image to the extension and have that image display as a background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let the user select a file, with `<input type="file">`
2. Turn the file into a data URL
3. Save the data URL with chrome.storage.local.set
4. Use a content script to replace the background image in web pages

Potential Problem: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/#unlimitedStorage

> Note: This permission applies only to Web SQL Database and application
> cache (see issue 58985). Also, it doesn't currently work with wildcard
> subdomains such as http://*.example.com.

Proof of concept:
https://github.com/GrippenDynamik/Set_Background_Image

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Set Background Image",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Set Background Image"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["/js/content_script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
async function action_onClicked(tab, onClickData) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        active: true,
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("/html/file_picker.html"),
    });
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(action_onClicked);
```

/html/file_picker.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <label for="file_picker">Choose an image to upload</label><br>
    <input type="file" id="file_picker" accept="image/*"><br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="button_clear">Clear background image</button>
    <br>
    <img id="image"><br>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/js/file_picker.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

/js/file_picker.js

```
function storage_onChanged(changes, areaName) {
    let settings = {};
    if (areaName == "local") {
        if (changes.image_data_url) {
            settings.image_data_url = changes.image_data_url.newValue ?? "";
        }
        if (changes.image_filename) {
            settings.image_filename = changes.image_filename.newValue ?? "none";
        }
    }
    set_image(settings);
}

function set_image(settings) {
    let image = document.getElementById("image");
    if (settings.image_data_url !== undefined) { image.src = settings.image_data_url; }
    if (settings.image_filename !== undefined) { image.alt = settings.image_filename; }
}

function remove_image() {
    chrome.storage.local.remove(["image_data_url", "image_filename"]);
}

function store_image() {
    if (this.files.length > 0) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
            chrome.storage.local.set({"image_data_url": reader.result, "image_filename": this.files[0].name});
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
}

// Initialization

chrome.storage.local.get(["image_data_url", "image_filename"])
    .then(items => {
        set_image({image_data_url: items.image_data_url ?? "", image_filename: items.image_filename ?? "none"});
    }
);

document.getElementById("file_picker").addEventListener("change", store_image);
document.getElementById("button_clear").addEventListener("click", remove_image);

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(storage_onChanged);
```

/js/content_script.js

```
function storage_onChanged(changes, areaName) {
    if (areaName == "local" && changes.image_data_url) {
        set_background_image(changes.image_data_url.newValue, true);
    }
}

function set_background_image(data_url, changed) {
    if (data_url) {
        // https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + data_url + "')";
    }
    else if (changed) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "initial";
    }
    else {
        console.log("You haven't 'uploaded' an image yet. Please click the extension action.");
    }
}

// Initialization

chrome.storage.local.get("image_data_url")
.then(items => set_background_image(items.image_data_url, false));

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(storage_onChanged);
```